# Assigning to property has no effect

Tags: c#, properties

I have a some code like this

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string DisplayValue
    {
       get 
       {
          if (fieldType == "ImageUri")
          {
             FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Value);
             return Path.Combine(file.Directory.Name, fileName);
          }
          else
          {
             return Value;
          }
       }
       set {}
    }
}
```

The "get" works fine but I can't change the DisplayValue.  When I assign a new value, it is not updated. SomeClass.DisplayValue = "something new" does not work.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to define a setter:

```
public string DisplayValue
{
   get 
   {
      // some logic
      return Value;
   }
   set 
   {
      // some logic
      Value = value;
   }
}
```

Note that the [`value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) keyword here represents the result of the right hand side of an assignment statement (as opposed to the identifier `Value`, which is a reference to the other property you defined).

**Further Reading**

- [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your setter is empty, so of course nothing happens. Your property as-written is effectively read only.

```
public string DisplayValue
{
   get 
   {
      ---some logic
      return Value;
   }
   set { Value = value; }
}
```

Is what you need, you set the backing field to the `value` keyword. You may have been confused by the auto-property syntax which hides this from you (you declared `Value` with it). When you manually declare a property, you have to **declare the whole thing** any "auto-ness" is lost.

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to change "Value." That's the original value that needs to stay the same. You did answer my question though, so thank you! I have to change my logic so DisplayValue can be changed but "Value" stays the same.

Comment: @LacHo, I thought that looked a little odd. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Yeah, I did not copy all the code so it indeed looked odd. The "getter" can return something other than Value or in some cases, the original value.

Comment: @LacHo There are a number of ways you could solve this but without knowing what 'some logic' is, it's hard to provide concrete direction. What exactly should happen if someone calls `obj.Value = "foo"`, then would `obj.DisplayValue` return `"foo"` in those cases? If a user calls `obj.DisplayValue = "foo"` would `obj.DisplayValue` ever return the original value would this always 'overwrite' the original value of `DisplayValue` (but leave `Value` unchanged)?

Comment: I updated my code so you can see. The getter is longer than that but I showed two cases so you get an idea. obj.Value should never be changed.

Comment: @LacHo, Ok. Is there an additional question in there or are you just providing future visitors with more context?

Comment: That and responding to p.s.w.g. I'm sure I can figure it out so thank you! I was just confused with the setter but it's clear now. I thought what I did was the same as public string DisplayValue {get;set;}

Comment: @LacHo Well I don't think you answered my questions (what do you want the exact behavior to be when someone calls those setters), but if you've got enough information to solve your problem, that's fine. Happy coding :)

Comment: I am good. I was just confused why my setter did not work because like I said I thought what I did was the same as {get;set;}. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as follows:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private string _displayValue;
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get 
        {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_displayValue))
           {
               if (fieldType == "ImageUri")
               {
                   FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Value);
                   return Path.Combine(file.Directory.Name, fileName);
               }
               else
               {
                   return Value;
               }
            }
            else
            {
                return _displayValue;
            }
       }
       set {_displayValue = value;}
    }
}
```